# Python - import files

Tags: python, python-import

Its not the first time I've come across this, but I'm having problems locating default import files.  For example I can find the collections.py file no problem, but inside this code is another import-: line 8 from _collections import deque, defaultdict.  For some reason I can't find the _collections file?

Comment: It's written in C, not Python.

Comment: @two-bit alchemist, that explains why I can't find it, thanks!